# catch Exception through inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have created an ApplicationException in my asp.net project. The idea is that I use this ApplicationExcpetion to throw Exceptions with a proper message to the user, and use the Exception to treat generic and unexpected errors with an generic message to the user.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get([FromUri]GetDto getDto)
{
    try
    {
        var response = await _application.Get(getDto);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
    }
    catch (ApplicationException ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            "There was an error on the request.");
    }
}
```

The problem is that I created a CustomException class that derives from the ApplicationException, and when it is thrown, it always stop on the Exception catch, istead of the ApplicationException catch as I was expecting.

```
public class ApplicationException : Exception
{
    public ApplicationException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }

    public ApplicationException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }
}
```

```
public class CustomException: ApplicationException
{
    private static readonly string MESSAGE = "customMessage";
    public CustomException(): base(MESSAGE) { } 
}
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong? What would be the right way to treat exceptions like that, separating customs applications exceptions from the rest?

Comment: One thing that's obviously Wrong here is that you catch an `Exception` instance and log *nothing* about it. You should at least log the details for internal use, regardless of what you return to the client. That would also allow you to, for example, see the actual type of the exception, so you can verify if it's really `CustomException` you're getting here (I suspect it's not).

Comment: Yes, but since I am catching ApplicationExceptions before the Exception catch, the error should fall into the ApplicationException catch, righ?

Comment: You did not write `ApplicationException` yourself, did you? There is [System.ApplicationException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.applicationexception?view=netframework-4.8) ...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Like you said a `catch(SomeException)` catches all exception types deriving from `SomeException`. So it seems Fildor is right, you are not catching _your_ `ApplicationException`, but `System.ApplicationException`. (or that mistake already happend at the inheritance).

Comment: right, as I wrote in my answer, the problem is that already existed an System.ApplicationException. Another solution i think would be to delete my ApplicationException class and make de CustomException derives from this System.ApplicationException that already exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized what I was doing wrong.

Already exist an ApplicationExcpetion class on c# libraries. The ApplicationException catch on my Controller was looking for Exception of type System.ApplicationException, except of the ApplicationException class that I created.

My solution was to simply rename from ApplicationException to DomainException, and it worked just fine :)